# List of AWS SERVICE values used for GetDimensionValues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I would like to know what are all the possible values are for the SERVICE property that you can get from the `AWS.CostExplorer.GetDimensionValues()` function. Note, I don't want to know this for my own account, I want to know all values that you can use.

I want to know this, so that I can call `AWS.CostExplorer.GetCostAndUsage` with a filter on the certain services I want to call (I just don't know their exact names). For example:

```
aws ce get-cost-and-usage --time-period Start=2022-12-01,End=2023-12-01 --granularity MONTHLY --metrics UnblendedCost --filter "Dimensions={Key=SERVICE,Values=['Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute']}"
```

I want to add more services to this but don't know their values.

Comment: Why don't you just query without filter, and collect the distinct values? I know you said you want to know all values not just for your account, but your explanation is to just query your account. So I don't see why you need the list of all values. Also, even if you get one today, they can add one more service tomorrow.

Comment: The sample call I'm making is a get-cost-and-usage call. While I can add a `--group-by Type=DIMENSION,Key=SERVICE` to break it down by SERVICE, what I'm really after is AWS's official list of what values you can use for SERVICE, so that I can filter by services that I'm interested in.